# Regex for string to contain at least one letter and number

Tags: regex

This regex expression will match the specified number of word characters, with a space in either side:

`(?<=\s)(?:\w){12}(?=\s)`

How can I modify this expression so that it returns only the string containing the mixed-alphanumeric result containing at least one letter and at least one number?  Here is the current [Regex Demo](https://regexr.com/73oed).

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to delimit it by white spaces? If there's comma after a "word", it doesn't count that word?

Comment: It doesn't have to be delimited by white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
\b(?=[^\s]*\d)(?=[^\s]*[a-zA-Z])\w{12}\b
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/Y6EnM6/1)

---

`\b` - word boundary

`(?=[^\s]*\d)` - continue matching if ahead is a number preceded with any amount of non-space characters.

`(?=[^\s]*[a-zA-Z])` - the same with letters

`\w{12}` - match 12 word characters

`\b` - word boundary

Comment: Are you sure about those spaces? How would spaces be right after \b?